# How to write a git post hook script which calls rundeck for auto merge the changes/commits done on release branch

Tags: rundeck

We have a release branch which has been cut off from develop. After testing the release branch developers started working on the bug fix by creating a feature branches from release branch. When the bug is fixed and feature branch is merged to release branch i need an auto merge from release branch to develop.For that i need a post hook script. Can you please me help how to write a script.

Comment: Have you considered using Gerrit?

Answer (score 0):

If you're set on a shell script, you can try using CURL, see https://gist.github.com/gschueler/783971 for a RunDeck related example.

Go over the API @ http://rundeck.org/docs/jp/api/index.html for detailed commands.